# negative lookahead (@!) together with very magic \v

Tags: regular-expression

I am struggling combining a negative lookahead assertion `@!` with the very magic specifier `\v`

I have a buffer with this content

```
<div class='vvv'>abc</div>
<div class='ttt'>abc</div>
```

and I want to search for all classes except vvv. I can do this like so

```
/class=.\(vvv\)\@!
```

This finds the second line (`class='ttt'`), as expected. Yet, when I try to search with the *very magic* modifier:

```
/\vclass=.(vvv)@!
```

the search finds both classes. I had wrongly assumed these searches to be equivalent. Why are they different?

Comment: be carefull with`\=`

Comment: My earlier comment was just ignorant, sorry. JJoao is quite right: the second, very magic pattern needs to be `\vclass\=.(vvv)@!`.

Comment: @JJoao you might want to turn your comment along with Peter's comment into an answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you wrote is perfect but in `\v` mode `=` needs protection.

```
\vclass\='(ttt)@!
```

In normal mode `\=` means *optional* (the same as `\?`). In 
`\v` mode, `=` means optional: `class=` ends up meaning `class|clas` (I would prefer `=` were just a normal char).

So, to mark the classes different form `ttt` we can:

```
:%s/\vclass\='(ttt)@!.{-}'/MARKED&/
```

When we have more complex "different-from" patterns it may be easier the long way:

```
:%s/\vclass\='(tt1|...)'/classAUX=\1/          rename exceptions
:%s/\vclass\='.{-}'/MARKED&/                   treat normal cases
:%s/\vclassAUX/class/                          unrename
```

\thanks{Peter Lewerin}